# Python - Trouble using inherited method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an instance of a class, within which I'm trying to use a method defined in the parent.

The code I have produces the following error:

```
if WordTrigger.isWordIn(story.getTitle()): return True:
```

> TypeError: unbound method isWordIn() must be called with WordTrigger instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Can anyone steer me in the right direction. i.e. should I be using super() 2.7 version? If so how?

```
class NewsStory(object):
    """
    Data structure for RSS data feed collector
    """
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self, cguid, ctitle, csubject, csummary, clink):
      # A globally unique identifier for this news story.
      self.cguid = cguid

      # The news story's headline.
      self.ctitle = ctitle

      # A subject tag for this story (e.g. 'Top Stories', or 'Sports').
      self.csubject = csubject

      # A paragraph or so summarizing the news story.
      self.csummary = csummary

      # A link to a web-site with the entire story.
      self.clink = clink

    def getGuid(self):
        return self.cguid

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.ctitle

    def getSubject(self):
        return self.csubject

    def getSummary(self):
        return self.csummary

    def getLink(self):
        return self.clink
#Trigger
class Trigger(object):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        """
        Returns True if an alert should be generated
        for the given news item, or False otherwise.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError

#WordTrigger
class WordTrigger(Trigger):

    def __init__(self, cword):
        # A globally unique identifier for this news story.
        self.cword = cword

    def isWordIn(self, ctext):
        # Checks if word is in text and returns true if present

        #Normalize case for word
        self.cword = self.cword.lower()

        # normalise text case and remove punctuation
        self.ctext = self.ctext.lower()
        exclude = set(str.punctuation)
        self.ctext = ''.join(ch for ch in self.ctext if ch not in exclude)

        # Check if word occurs in text
        if self.cword in self.ctext:
            return True
        else:
            return False

#TitleTrigger
class TitleTrigger(WordTrigger):

    def evaluate(self, story):
        """
        Returns True if an alert should be generated
        for the given news item, or False otherwise.
        """    
        if WordTrigger.isWordIn(story.getTitle()): return True
        else: return False
```

Comment: I should also include this code as well:

Comment: class NewsStory(object):

    def __init__(self, cguid, ctitle, csubject, csummary, clink):
 
      self.cguid = cguid
      

      self.ctitle = ctitle
      
      self.csubject = csubject
      
      self.csummary = csummary
      

      self.clink = clink
        
    def getTitle(self):
        return self.ctitle

Comment: Thanks, just edited it, much easier to read.

Comment: Hmm, I recognize this ... Are you currently enrolled in a MITx/edX course?

Comment: Yes I'm enrolled in the MIT/edX course

Answer (score 0):

In your class `TitleTrigger`, use `self`.  You access the method through an instance of the class, not on the class object itself.

```
def evaluate(self, story):
    """
    Returns True if an alert should be generated
    for the given news item, or False otherwise.
    """    
    if self.isWordIn(story.getTitle()): return True
    else: return False
```

Comment: I tried using self earlier, but it bombed out. Now that you have told me the correct way to access the parent method using self, I can look up to the parent and see if I've screwed up something there. Standby... Thanks

Comment: @dje In the code you posted, you didn't create any instances of any of your classes.  To use the classes, you must create instances of them.